# Can Byte Buddy create fields and method annotations at runtime?

Tags: java, android, annotations, runtime, byte-buddy

I would like to implement this 3rd-party annotation to map my class's fields/properties to my database table columns.  I can easily implement the annotations at compile time (as shown in the example code below) but I can't find a way to do this at runtime. (I am loading the library at runtime using reflection.)

My question is how can I implement the same mapping annotation when loading a library at run time? Can Byte Buddy handle this for Android?

```
//3rd party annotation code
package weborb.service;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface MapToProperty {
    String property();
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//Here is the implementation using non-reflection
import weborb.service;
    Class Person
    {
        @MapToProperty(property="Person_Name")
        String name;

        @MapToProperty(property="Person_Age")
        int age;

        @MaptoProperty(property="Person_Name")
        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        @MaptoProperty(property="Person_Name")
        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @MaptoProperty(property="Person_Age")
        public int getAge()
        {
             return this.age;
        }

        @MaptoProperty(property="Person_Age")
        public void setAge(int age)
        {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, please refer to [the *Annotations* section of the documentation](http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) for details.

You can build an annotation using an `AnnotationDescription.Builder` by:

```
AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(MapToProperty.class)
                             .define("property", "<value>")
                             .build();
```

The resulting `AnnotationDescription` can be supplied to a dynamic type builder as an argument:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(Object.class)
  .defineField("foo", Void.class)
  .annotateField(annotationDescription)
  .make();
```

Similarly, it works for methods.

Comment: Class Person
    {
         String name;
         int age;

        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

         public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge()
        {
             return this.age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age)
        {
            this.age = age;
        }

Comment: Thank you.  Can I apply similar to add annotations at run time on an existing class?  I'm using Byte-Buddy, Byte-Buddy-Android, and dx.

Comment: In theory, yes, but Android does not implement Java's instrumentation API. Therefore, it is only possible if a class file is embedded into an application and if the modified class is loaded by a new class loader.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter could you please explain how to make it work for methods without changing the method implementation? Would really appreciate, cannot find a good example :(